# How to select header in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need a tableView where I can select a section to add an item to it. How? Should I increase the height from 22px to 44px keep the background style and implement an event handler on the sectionnview? What aproach do you use to add item on a section?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    foundIndex=FALSE;
    for (int i=0; i<[indexArray count]; i++)
    {
        _currentRow=[[indexArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        if(_currentRow==indexPath.section)
        {
            foundIndex=TRUE;
        }
    }
    if (foundIndex==TRUE)
    {
        return 100;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }   
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIButton *btnCollapse = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnCollapse setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 303, 50)];
    [btnCollapse setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [btnCollapse addTarget:self action:@selector(touchedSection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnCollapse.tag = section+600;
    [headerView addSubview:btnCollapse];

    UILabel *lot_title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 2, 270, 20)];
    lot_title.numberOfLines=3;
    lot_title.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lot_title.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[MyConsignmentData objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"lot_title"]];
    lot_title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    lot_title.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];

    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(lot_title.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize textSize1 = [lot_title.text sizeWithFont:lot_title.font constrainedToSize:maxSize];
    lot_title.frame=CGRectMake(13, 2, 270, textSize1.height);

    if (textSize1.height+10<40)
    {
        return 40;
    }
    else
    {
        return textSize1.height+10;
    }
}
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 50)];

    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280,tableView.sectionHeaderHeight/2+5 , 22, 22)];

    foundIndex=FALSE;
    for (int i=0; i<[indexArray count]; i++)
    {
        _currentRow=[[indexArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        if(_currentRow==section)
        {
            foundIndex=TRUE;
        }
    }
    if (foundIndex==TRUE)
    {
        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"down-arrow-active.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"right-arrow-deactive.png"];
    }

    [headerView addSubview:img];

    UIButton *btnCollapse = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnCollapse setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 303, 50)];
    [btnCollapse setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [btnCollapse addTarget:self action:@selector(touchedSection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnCollapse.tag = section+600;
    [headerView addSubview:btnCollapse];

     UIImageView *imgbac;
    if (textSize1.height+10<40)
    {
        imgbac = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 0, 303, 40)];
    }
    else
    {
        imgbac = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 0, 303, textSize1.height+10)];
    }

    imgbac.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mybid-box-bg.png"];
    [headerView addSubview:imgbac];

    [headerView addSubview:imgbac];
    [headerView addSubview:lot_title];
    [headerView addSubview:img];
    [headerView addSubview:btnCollapse];
    headerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    return headerView;
}
- (IBAction)touchedSection:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger _index=[sender tag]-600;
    foundIndex=FALSE;
    NSInteger stored;
    for (int i=0; i<[indexArray count]; i++)
    {
        _currentRow=[[indexArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        if(_currentRow==_index)
        {
            stored=i;
            foundIndex=TRUE;
        }
    }
    if (foundIndex==TRUE)
    {
        [indexArray removeObjectAtIndex:stored];
    }
    else
    {
        [indexArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:_index]];
    }

    [tableview reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it with the `UITableViewDelegate`.

Create a custom section `headerView` ,and then add Tap gesture to it.

LIKE :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapRecogniser = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureHandler:)] autorelease];
[singleTapRecogniser setDelegate:self];
singleTapRecogniser.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
singleTapRecogniser.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;   
[yourHeaderView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapRecogniser];
```

and then:

```
//This method will be called on Tap of section heade
- (void) handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
}
```